# Confusion of [edf] tag between European Data Format and Earliest Deadline First scheduling

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

I work in the electro-medical field, and our products use the [European Data Format](http://edfplus.info/) file format.

When searching for the [edf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/edf) tag (which is correctly mapped to this file format), from the total of 7 questions with this tag, I found some which actually refer to [Earliest Deadline First scheduling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earliest_deadline_first_scheduling).

So, my question is: should the [edf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/edf) tag be modified, and/or should another one (for example [edfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/edfs) or [earliest-deadline-first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/earliest-deadline-first) be created?

Comment: Perhaps [edf-scheduling]?

Comment: [edf-scheduling] seems good, and possibly changing [edf] to [edf-format] could be useful (that is, eliminating the ambiguous [edf] tag altogether)